# Why simplexml_load_file does not work on localhost?

Tags: javascript, php

I am beginner in php and got a problem with reading xml file.
So I'm trying to parse my xml file with simplexml_load_file but it return such problem:

GET http://localhost:9000/registation.php 500 (Internal Server Error);

here is a php code:

```
<?php $users = simplexml_load_file("usersdb.xml"); ?>
```

Why it does not work?Xml file is in a same directory as php file.I also allowed url fopen in php.ini but it still not working.HELP!!!

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the script crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the PHP error log to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying (and solving) the problem. P.S. If you don't have error logging set up yet in your PHP install, see this guide to get it working: https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ .

Comment: P.P.S. allow_url_fopen is not useful here, because, as you said yourself, you're trying to access a local file in the same folder. allow_url_fopen allows you to write scripts that open remote files as if they are local files. This is potentially a security risk and in most cases it should be switched off unless you really need it for a specific reason.

Comment: Try checking the registration file for syntax errors too, from the command line run:
`php -l registration.php`